# Dates using haven read_sas in R

Tags: r, date, sas

I'm reading in a sas data set using `haven::read_sas` and I'm having an issue with columns that are supposed to be dates but are being read in as numeric.

Is there a way to specify when using `read_sas()` to interpret column `X` as a character or as a date? If it's helpful, the entries in the sas data set are of the form `YYYYMM` so something like `202003` and `read_sas` is taking them in as numeric.

Should mention that this date column is erroneously being read in (the numbers are messed up) so just modifying the column ex-post using `as.Date` or `as.character` does not work. For example, `202005` is being read in as `22036`.

Comment: Added the answer as requested @Joe

Comment: So you seem to be misinterpreting how SAS prints/display values.  A date that is displayed using the YYMMN6. format will display as digits in a YYYYMM style, but the actual value is the number of days since 1960.  So it sounds like the HAVEN package did to understand that YYMMN is a format used to displays date values and so it just converting the raw value into a number instead of converting them into a date.

Comment: haven has a limited [set of SAS formats that it recognizes](https://github.com/tidyverse/haven/blob/d913105db0d485f95c3965bac13d0c42b9f7cb7d/src/haven_types.cpp#L53-L72). Sounds like you have stumbled on one that's not supported. You could open a feature request to get that added for future releases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SAS uses January 1, 1960 as an origin date and all dates are a numeric value for days between the origin and the specified date. Any date prior to January 1, 1960 will be negative and any date after will be positive. After importing the data with `haven` you can format it as a date using this origin.

```r
x <- 22036

as.Date(x , origin = "1960-01-01")
#> [1] "2020-05-01"
```

For the SAS date documentation you can see [here](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002200738.htm).